# What’s behind this surprising art shift?

Tags: cosmere, white-sand

In *White Sand* 2, by Brandon Sanderson (the Kindle version, at least), there seems to be an astonishing art shift, unexplained and unannounced, at  about page 129. Compare these soft tones:

[image]
To these crisp lines:

[image]

There may be some other slight art shifts. For example, up until page 136, Kenton’s skin seems to be curiously light compared to the previous volume, which seems especially odd given

> his Nightside descent.

But it switches to a darker shade about there:

[image]

In a serial work, I’d expect that another artist had taken over,  but I’ve never seen this in a completed published graphic novel. What’s going on?

Comment: The only thing I can find quickly is that the book was delayed quite a bit.  It wouldn't surprise me at all if they had to switch artists midstream if the first one (Julius Gopez) couldn't meet deadlines.  That said, there's usually some comments on that.  I can't find mention of a reason, or any particular change of status for the artist or the credits on the books, just a fair number of people just as confused by the art shift.

Comment: OK, I found a brief mention of a new artist (Julius Otha?) in one of book's reviews, but I can't find any other info, so I don't know how accurate it is.

Comment: @Radhil - I found the same thread, and a lot of people talk about an artist change but not who the new one was.

Comment: @Radhil the other artist is actually mentioned in the front of the book as well.

Comment: @MartinEnder - I don't actually have the book, thus the googling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/203786/51379), the proximal reason for the change in art is a change to a new artist. While we can't really know for certain the *motivation* behind this unusual action, I think we can take a guess.

In essence, Sanderson [seems to have felt](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/35-arcanum-unbounded-hoboken-signing/#e4399) that his original vision for the book wasn't being carried out by the artist, Julius Gopez. In particular, he felt like the artist was deviating from his script in such a way as to reinforce racial and ethnic stereotypes.

> **Ravi**:  I'm curious how you were <feeling about whole process of> the graphic novel. <Specifically how you felt about the whole thing
>   translating,> because I have the draft.
>
> **Brandon Sanderson**:  Uh-huh.
>
> **Ravi**:   <You were kind enough to send me that>. You know, you were very descriptive.
>
> **Brandon Sanderson**:  <And it didn't translate well?>
>
> Ravi:  Not so much-- although I did see <glimpses of you popping
>   through>.
>
> **Brandon Sanderson**:  Yeah, so, I focus on the positives. <But there might be some things I might not agree with.>
>
> **Ravi**:  I think that's fair. Of course.
>
> **Brandon Sanderson**:  And I-- what we came up with was the <a list of a few things>... *inaudible* Like the only one that really bothered
>   <me> was... where is the big battle?
>
> *searches through the graphic novel*
>
> <The big splash page> right there. I'm like... <when did this turn
>   into> white people verse brown people? You've read the book. This
>   isn't about white versus brown. This is, again, how did we end up with
>   white versus brown? Why aren't these people wearing armor? These guys
>   are the ones that are outcasts and these are the high society.

He seems to be referring to this page, among others:

[image: A very busy page from a comic. Divided into three uneven sections, by diagonal lines, each section shows pale skinned warriors in white fighting more tan skinned adversaries. The detail of each page blurs lines between each subject, making distinguishing individuals difficult.]

Moreover, as hinted at in the last paragraph ("these guys are the ones that are outcasts and these are the high society"), he felt that the art played into stereotypes of cultured Europeans and primitive dark-skinned desert people, which [he says was the opposite](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cosmere/comments/567j1t/white_sand_question/d8phojo/?context=3) of what he was trying to convey (what with the Nightsiders having more technological advancement and seeing the Daysiders as primitive, for instance).

While he also blames himself here, it's not too  hard to read between the lines and see that he blames the artist somewhat, particularly in the context of the previous quote.

> **Brandon Sanderson**:  Yes, that's part of it. Though I don't think we got in the graphic novel some of the important worldbuilding elements,
>   such as the armor that melts when sprayed with water, the unique forms
>   of fighting, and the fact that the people you assume are the advanced
>   ones (because they live in buildings instead of tents) are actually
>   far less technologically developed than the ones who live out in the
>   desert. (Because on this planet, that's the "good" land while the low
>   sands are the less fertile parts.)
>
> That was a dynamic that was very hard to get across in the book,
>   though, and I don't know that my skill at the time was up to it. I was
>   disappointed in the graphic novel once the colors and final art came
>   back to discover a number of pages that looked like brave Europeans
>   fighting savage desert people--which was the reverse of what I'd been
>   trying to accomplish. (But is part of our cultural biases, so I'm not
>   surprised it was how the artists ended up interpreting it. And I'm to
>   blame for not reinforcing the idea stronger back when it could have
>   been changed.)

Indeed, if we look at that image, it's pretty easy to see that. It's been a while since I read the original White Sand novel, but as I recall Kerzta was implied to be industrialized (for Dayside), and having armor with religious markings (of the sort that Ais wears, for instance), not being shirtless, spear-wielding berserkers. And it's fairly easy to see that they're portrayed as having darker skin in this picture, which I don't think was the case in White Sand Prime. They certainly wouldn't have darker skin than Kenton, since he has some Nightside ancestry. The overall effect is very *300*-esque, with the sophisticated philosopher-kings of the Diem fighting the non-white barbarians of Kertza, rather than the powerful, religious empire of the Kertza fighting the insolvent Diem living on the fringes.

It seems that Brandon was not happy with this art, laying much of the blame on the artist. With such harsh criticism in public, he might have been even more critical behind closed doors. It's not hard to see from here why Brandon might have changed artists. It's also possible that these comments induced a desire in Gopez to leave as well.

Answer (score 4):

There was indeed a *forced* change to a new artist. The "forced" word comes from the highest source, the [State of the Sanderson](https://brandonsanderson.com/state-of-the-sanderson-2018/). As of now, team Sanderson has been [silent](https://www.reddit.com/r/brandonsanderson/comments/82jvis/annoyingly_i_have_to_wait_until_i_finish_work/dvbgw18) as to why this artist change took place. Finally, the third volume is due in June (already available for pre-order at amazon) and the artist is another, new one, Fritz Casas.

Comment: We will probably never know why, but I might have an inkling. Let me see.... I remember seeing a complaint Sanderson had. I just need to find it.

Comment: Ah-ah! He says it [here](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/131/#e3963).

Comment: "That was a dynamic that was very hard to get across in the book, though, and I don't know that my skill at the time was up to it. I was disappointed in the graphic novel once the colors and final art came back to discover a number of pages that looked like brave Europeans fighting savage desert people--which was the reverse of what I'd been trying to accomplish. (But is part of our cultural biases, so I'm not surprised it was how the artists ended up interpreting it. And I'm to blame for not reinforcing the idea stronger back when it could have been changed.)"

Comment: In fact, I like your answer, but I should probably write my own.

Comment: Wait, though: was that change *within* the first graphic novel? Because your sources seem to be talking about it being *between* books.

Comment: That's why I was confused by your comment! Indeed, that WoB you quoted is about the first book - the Vol.2 was not yet released. It is my understanding that Vol.1 was done by Julius Gopez, Vol.2 up to the last(s) chapter by Julius Gopez too, Vol.2 last(s) chapters by another artist (Julius Otha?) and Vol.3, not yet released, by Fritz Casas.

Comment: Right, OK. I'm writing an answer to complement yours, focusing on the potential motivation behind the change, then. There are some other quotes that I've found.

Comment: Even though he made that comment before he switched artists, when an author falls out so publicly with an artist, and then they switch artists shortly thereafter, I think it's obvious what likely happened. When they criticize an artist like that in public (looking at the other quote I found, in particular), they're likely being more critical behind closed doors.